# Javascript Library not working with React Native release build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

My company have a javascript library that contains all the core logic of our web app (written with React). This library is built using typescript and compiled down to es2015.

When adding this library to our react native app we've encountered a weird behaviour where the code works fine when running the app with the debug version but doesn't work when running release builds.

We don't understand why this issue is happening especially because we aren't writing any code in this library that we wouldn't write in the app. And we also tried to copy the code from the library to our app and it worked fine.

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Is the plugin trying to access some browser resources that it would be able to receive by connecting remote debugger?. Try it without connecting any external debugger tools.

Comment: are you able to create a release build for the same, and then your code wouldn't work or you are not able to create release build.

Comment: @PritishVaidya we are not using any browser specific resources or apis.

Comment: @Prince we are able to create the release build but the code that uses resources from the library doesn't work

Comment: Is there a repo or codebase for the library?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the codebase